# IBM Cloud Functions to MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, watson-assistant

I am trying to read some data from my MySql DB using a function (Node), the code bellow is what i had tryed so far.

```
    /**
  *
  * main() será executado quando você chamar essa ação
  *
  * @param As ações do Cloud Functions aceitam um único parâmetro, que deve ser um objeto JSON.
  *
  * @return A saída dessa ação, que deve ser um objeto JSON.
  *
  */
var sql = require('mysql');

    var connection = sql.createConnection({
      host: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    user: 'ccccccccccccccc',
    password: 'wwwwwwwwwwww',
    database: 'dsssssssssssssss'
    });
function main(params) {
 try {

   connection.connect();

   var sql="SELECT * FROM db_a43aea_frenew.funcionarios where Owner = 208 AND CodigoVendedor = 20";
   console.log("Olaaaaaaaa....");
   
   connection.query(sql,function(err,result){
       return{message:result};
       //console.log(result);
   })
   //console.log(result);
   //console.log(rows);
   connection.end();

 }
 catch (e) {
   return { message:"error ==> " + e};
  //return{message:"FALSE"}; 
 }
}
```

But it produced no results. And have no error also.

Can someone give some hint of where the problem is..

Thank you.

Comment: One additional information : I put some LOG in the lines and realize that it look that the "connection.query" is executed and I got no error. How can I display the content of resulting query..?

Comment: No one so far....(:

Comment: Obs: I ran it on VS CODE using NODEMON and it worked perfectly.